# Python and how to get specific text from HTML using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a specific text content in html page by using Selenium webdriver class name. The HTML code are below:-

```
<tr> 
   <th>
   <td class="max-captured">174.26 kp/s</td>
   <td class="max-captured">0 p/s </td>
</tr>
```

I want to capture just the text "p/s". Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can use css_selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr th .max_captured:nth-child(2)').text
```